# I moved the vertex to the grab, but it breaks strangely

Tags: modeling

[image]

At first, I tried to move it by pressing g.
Second, I tried to move with the propotional editor turned on.
I deleted the shape key and the ones that are rigged.
I copied it from the body to make shoes.
The body doesn't crack even if you press g, but only these copied shoes break.

[image]

Comment: Set Origin > Origin to Geometry. And disabble Mesh Symmetry arround the X axis.

Comment: wow it's work. thank you so much.